# How does flask auto reload affect performance?

Tags: python, performance, flask

```
app = Flask(__name__）
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
app.jinja_env.auto_reload = True
```

How does flask auto reload affect performance ?

And should I enable AutoReload in production ?

Comment: You should never enable auto reload in production.

Comment: Thank you!  I hunch that but I don't know how to explain it exactly.